# Cloudbees 504 Gateway Time-out Deploying Play Framework App

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, cloudbees

I'm new to Cloudbees. I'm following the instructions here: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework

I can run the play web app without an issue on local. In addition, I've successfully deployed to Heroku, but switched to Cloudbees when I learned websockets was not supported.

However, I'm getting a 504 Gateway Time-out when I try to deploy to cloudbees. Am I missing a step? I was under the impression using the Cloudbees SDK allows me to deploy without using the SBT plugin.

```
C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat>play dist
[info] Loading project definition from C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat
\project
[info] Set current project to websocket-chat (in build file:/C:/play-2.1.0/sampl
es/java/websocket-chat/)
[info] Wrote C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat\target\scala-2.10\websock
et-chat_2.10-1.0.pom

Your application is ready in C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat\dist\webs
ocket-chat-1.0.zip

[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jun 20, 2013 2:53:34 PM

C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat>bees app:deploy -a my_username/chatroom
 -t play2 dist/websocket-chat-1.0.zip
Deploying application my_username/chatroom (environment: ): dist\websocket-chat-1
.0.zip
Application parameters: {containerType=play2}
........................uploaded 25%
........................uploaded 50%
........................uploaded 75%
........................upload completed
deploying application to server(s)...
Application my_username/chatroom deployed: http://chatroom.my_username.cloudbees.n
et

C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat>bees app:proxy:update -a my_username/cha
troom1 httpVersion=1.1
Are you sure you want to update this application proxy [my_username/chatroom]: (y
/n) y
application proxy for my_username/chatroom : updated

C:\play-2.1.0\samples\java\websocket-chat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to deploy using the SBT method described in the Cloudbees documentation: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework This document is fairly comprehensive.

To be fair, installing the Cloudbees SDK helped so I didn't have to install config files when setting up with the SBT plugin.

However, I turned to the git hub project for the configuration of SBT, as the Cloudbees documentation may be slightly behind. The sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin code/docs can be found here: https://github.com/CloudBees-community/sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin

I must admit I don't complete understand the deployment using SBT. My project now **successfully** appears on the web (and works with websockets!), yet I still got these command line outputs. I'm not sure if it'll affect performance at the moment. I've included it below for reference, skipping uninteresting sections with ellipsis notation.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at cloudbees.Plugin$.cloudbees$Plugin$$performDeploy(cloudbees.scala:236
)
        at cloudbees.Plugin$$anonfun$deployTask$1.apply(cloudbees.scala:108)
        at cloudbees.Plugin$$anonfun$deployTask$1.apply(cloudbees.scala:105)

...

Caused by: edu.stanford.ejalbert.exception.BrowserLaunchingInitializingException
: unable to find config file: /edu/stanford/ejalbert/launching/windows/windowsCo
nfig.properties

...

WARNING

Looks like you are using a deprecated version of Play's SBT Project (PlayProject
 in project/Build.scala).
We are adding all of the new Play artifacts to your libraryDependencies for now
but consider switching to the new API (i.e. play.Project).

For any migration related issues, please consult the migration manual at http://
www.playframework.org
...
```

Comment: That is good to hear - the play command *is* sbt - so this just hooks into it. I expect it takes care of any file quirks/permissions a bit better than dist - you are on windows I note.
That error happens on the command line when you deploy - I take it? I wouldn't worry about that in that case - looks windows specific  - it looks like it wan'ts to find a browser executable so it can launch the app in the browser (just convenience, not required!)

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
bees app:tail -a username/appname
```

and take a look at the logs - it may shed some light. 
Also - you can unzip the dist locally - and try running that. Running from the dist can sometimes be slightly different from running from the play command (which is unfortunate that play works that way, and Heroku run it in non production mode).

But the log should shed some light - otherwise, if you can open a ticket with your account then we can look into the specifics (so you don't have to say it here!).

Comment: I'll open a ticket if we need my account information, but hopefully we can rule on the issue here. My log states I'm listening on 0.0.0.0:8660. I'm not sure if this is right. My server log: 

`Play server process ID is 28917
[[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
[[37minfo[0m] play - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:8660`

Comment: I tried the zip deploy method and now I get a 502 error. The logs state something about "Could not find the main class: play.core.server.NettyServer.  Program will exit."

Comment: OK I was able to find your app (the first one) - it isn't responding on the port it is listening to - I don't know why. The "dist" of your app can be different to what "play run" does - try unzipping the dist and running it locally to see if it responds. Play is hanging for some reason - not sure why. If you can get that running - may be worth opening a ticket and uploading the dist so we can look at it.

Comment: Given it is using websocket - can you deploy a simpler "starter" play2 app to ensure the dist from your machine works, and then work forward to your one? as I want to know the problem is around the dist, or your application code + dist.

Comment: Also - ignore your second app - zipping up the whole thing won't work - you can delete that app.

Comment: Based on the play [documentation link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Production), I don't have a way of testing a production mode application on my Windows platform. Windows throws a initialization of VM error.   Luckily, the sbt deploy method works (even though it complains).

Comment: Great - go with SBT - it does the right thing - that error won't hurt you. All the best!